# find files not matching list of filename patterns

Tags: bash, find, perl

I find myself needing to find and identify extraneous files (out of about 900K files on a 2T drive).  There are lots of files that I want to keep, and I have filename patterns for these known good files.  What I want is to locate those files that don't fit any of the patterns.

*How do I find files not matching a list of filename patterns?*

I can run `find` to get a list of all files, and I could use `grep -v` on the result, using a list of patterns stored in a file.  Is this the canonical method, or do you have a concise way to find these non-conforming files?

---

*Clarification - based upon the answers, here is a little more information.  I expect to have numerous patterns (>20, maybe >100), I want to store them in a file and certainly want an easy way to add new ones.  I would prefer to avoid directly editing a large list of find parameters (fragile), but building that list might work.*

Comment: The Perl answer assumes you have the patterns stored in a separate file and reads from that. It tries to match the file names against the patterns either literally or by interpreting the patterns as globs.

Comment: I've edited my answer to address the "patterns in a file" requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you mention Perl...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find qw{find};

my %patterns;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  $patterns{$_}++;
}

die "No pattern supplied\n" unless keys %patterns;

find( 
    sub{
           my $matches_a_pattern=0;
           for my $pattern (keys %patterns){
               my $glob_pattern = $pattern;
               for($glob_pattern){
                   s/\./\\./g;
                   s/\*/.*/g;
                   s/\?/./g;
               }
               $matches_a_pattern++ if ( /\Q$pattern\E/ or /$glob_pattern/);
           }

           print "$File::Find::name\n" unless $matches_a_pattern;
     }
    , '.' )
```

Invoke this as

```
/path/to/my/script file_with_patterns
```

Replace the `.` at the end with the top of the tree you want to walk.

Answer (score 28):

`find(1)` is powerful enough to do what you need. Simply collect all of the conforming names into an expression using parentheses, then negate it to show *non-conforming* file names. For example, to show all files *not* named `*.txt`, `*.bz2`, or `*.zip`:

```
$ find . \! \( -name \*.txt -o -name \*.bz2 -o -name \*.zip \)
```

You can use `-not` instead of `\!` with GNU and BSD `find`. It isn't POSIX compliant, but it doesn't require an escape to prevent the shell from interpreting it.

To build the expression from patterns in a file, it's a small matter of shell scripting:

```
#!/bin/sh
set --
while IFS= read -r pattern
do
    set -- "$@" -o "$pattern"
done < .fnpatterns
if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then
  shift
  set -- -not \( "$@" \)
fi
find . "$@"
```

This expects a file in the current directory called `.fnpatterns` with one pattern per line. To mimic the one-liner above, it would need to contain:

```
*.txt
*.bz2
*.zip
```

Note that the shell script escapes the `*` characters in the patterns for you.

You can make this arbitrarily complex. Some ideas:

- Add `-type f` to the `find` command so it only shows normal files, not directories.
- Pass the pattern file name in as an argument instead of expecting it in a fixed location
- Keep the pattern file where it is, but add `-o -name .fnpatterns` to the built-up `find` command so it doesn't show up in the output. (This would also avoid the need for the `shift` hack to "eat" the lead `-o` in the built-up expression.)
- Add actions to the `find` command via `-exec` or similar.
- Allow blank lines or comments in the patterns file

Comment: what does `set --` mean?

Comment: @Roberto: The first one clears all of the script's positional parameters: `$1`, `$2`, etc. The second appends `-o $pattern` to the parameter list, so that at the end of the loop we have all the patterns from the `.fnpatterns` file as if passed to the script in quasi-`find` expression form. We've got an extra `-o` on the front, so we `shift` it off, then wrap the whole thing in a negation with the third `set --` command. Now our positional parameter list contains a valid `find` expression which we pass using `"$@"`.