# Emulating git status --ignored in non-repository folder

Tags: grep, find, regular-expression, git

This might be in essence a duplicate of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96432/45354), however the perl script provided did not work in my case as far as I can tell. There are also many questions about finding multiple patterns, but they are surprisingly difficult to search through because Google doesn't seem to make a difference between a "file of patterns" and a "pattern of filename".

I would like to emulate the behaviour of

```
git status --ignored --porcelain | awk '{print $2}'
```

in a non-repository folder. That is, **I would like to list files and directories which match the patterns listed in a (specified) file, with the following constraints**:

- the patterns are written with the [gitignore syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format), in particular empty lines and comments should be ignored by the script;
- the script should walk from the current working directory;
- the script should **not** walk into matched directories (ie, a match is always a leaf), or into symbolic links.

Here is a simple example:

```
$> cat .gitignore 
    *.DS_Store*
    tmp/
    a/**/foo

$> tree -a .
.
|-- .DS_store
|-- .gitignore
|-- a
|   |-- b
|   |   |-- foo
|   |   |   `-- file
|   |   `-- tmp
|   |-- foo
|   `-- tmp
|       `-- file
`-- c
    |-- .DS_Store?
    `-- foo

5 directories, 8 files

$> git status --ignored --porcelain | awk '{print $2}'
    .DS_store
    a/b/foo/
    a/foo
    a/tmp/
    c/.DS_Store?
```

If possible at all, I would be particularly interested in solutions which work both on osx and linux, and which can be extended to consider patterns in posix-egrep format instead. For that last part, something similar to `find . -print | egrep -f patternfile` could work, although this would walk into matching directories, which could potentially make things very slow.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of a directory and the listing you would like to see. Assume we don't know what the git command does (and we shouldn't need to know some other command in order to understand your question).

Comment: This is exactly the threshold at which you'd give up on shell and write the thing in Perl or Python.

Comment: @terdon Is the example I included helpful, or too complicated?

Comment: @SatoKatsura That is fine with me, I was just reluctant about reinventing the wheel, since `git-status` already does what I want. I was wondering whether it was possible to run the command in a non-repository, and if I have to implement this myself, if there was a library/package you would recommend for parsing gitignore syntax?

Comment: The example is fine, but are you sure about your results? Why is `c/.DS_Store?` shown if `*.DS_Store*` is in `.gitignore`? Why is `a/b/foo/` shown if you are ignoring `a/**/foo`? I also don't understand what you mean by "script should not walk into matched directories". You seem to be descending into subdirs there.

Comment: @terdon Sorry for the confusing question; I am using `git status --ignored` to show the files that _are_ ignored. My question is about matching the patterns listed in a file with the gitignore syntax, not ignoring them. As for the matching directory, I apologise for not including this in my example; if there was a non-empty folder `a/b/foo/bar`, then it should not be listed (or indeed, walked through at all), since `a/b/foo` is ignored.

Comment: OK, please [edit] and make all this clear. You are starting with the assumption that everyone knows what `git` is and how its flags are supposed to work. This is a site about Unix and Linux and while many of us are programmers and do use git, many don't. I do, but don't know the details of the `--ignored` option. So forget `git`, just explain what you need. Show us the patterns (there's no such thing as a gitignore pattern, AFAIK, those are regular shell globs) you want to exclude and the output you want to see (instead of what you don't want to see).

Comment: @terdon I will edit later on, but it seems that `rsync -a --list-only --include='*/' --include-from='/path/to/file' --exclude='*' .` is getting close to what I want, although I am not sure there is a way to make rsync understand extglobs.